# Apache Beam for audio signal/stream processing

Tags: python, audio, apache-beam

I am working on speech-like recognition, thus processing audio signals i.e. applying a bunch of transforms and digital signal processing (DSP) techniques to raw audio signals in order to get valuable representations which are then fed into machine learning algorithms.

My code base is entirely written in Matlab and works only on finite (bounded) signals. I am planning to migrate to a solution where I can handle both finite and infinite (streams) audio signals, preferably in python (mainly for third party library availability in both machine learning and audio signal processing).

After some research, I found that Apache Beam would be well suited in my case, but, it seems that certain functionalities are not available in the python SDK, like the windowing concept which is super important in my case, both for bounded and unbounded signals (typically, my code process frames/windows of 32 milliseconds).

So, I am seeking advice on:

- The pertinence of Apache beam (python SDK) for audio signal
  processing;
- How to go with the limitation I've just mentioned;
- Is there other alternatives in my case;

Answer (score 0):

First, generally speaking, I would avoid doing heavy DSP using Python: it will inevitably result in some slow performance compared to C/C++.

Now I don't know much about Apache Beam but it does not seem adapted to audio signal processing at all, rather to processing of large amounts of text data. Actually, I could not find any mention of the word "audio" on their website…

#### So, where to go from here?

At the end of the day, you probably your program to be written in C/C++. You could use, for instance:

- *Matlab Coder*, which allows you to convert Matlab code in C/C++. Not sure about the performance and how close will it get you to the final result.
- [*PortAudio*](http://www.portaudio.com), which is a relatively low-level audio library and will surely allow you to make what you want.
- other libraries

You can also try to mix *Matlab Coder* and *PortAudio*: convert the specific algorithms that you have in C/C++ using *Matlab Coder* and integrate them into the skeleton that *PortAudio* gives you.

The basic principles of *PortAudio* are:

- it is platform-independent and open-source
- you define a callback function, which is the function which will be called whenever you have to process an audio buffer. If you process a file, it will be split in small chunks which will be used as audio buffers. If you work with a real-time stream, each buffer you receive from "the outside world" will be sent to this callback function.

Comment: Thank you @filaton for your clarifications. I took into account the concerns about performance and find out `Essentia`, a library developed by University of Pompeu Fabra, Barcelona. It is written in C++ with python bindings. It provides in addition to standard processing, a streaming mode which allows to specify your pipeline as a directed graph.

Comment: Well, *Essentia* is mainly a music analysis library (so *a priori* not well suited for speech-recognition), though it includes standard DSP algorithms. If it doesn't work for you, you can also use *PyAudio*, which is a Python binding of the *PortAudio* library I mentioned in my first answer.
(Btw, if you are satisfied by my answer, you can mark it as accepted. Welcome on StackOverflow :))